# Spring Validation throws Error Committing Transaction

Tags: java, spring

**UPDATE**
Based on suggestion below, I've included

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Also changed method signature to:

```
public String updateProducts(@Valid  @ModelAttribute("updateProductsForm")    BindingResult result, UpdateProductsForm updateProductsForm, ModelMap modelMap) {
```

The result is a different Exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.validation.BindingResult]: Specified class is an interface
```

I am attempting to get Spring to a validate form field. I've setup Hibernate validation as a dependency:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then in my object, I have this:

```
@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
@javax.validation.constraints.Size(min=1,max=255)
```

In the Object Model I have:

```
  @Column(
    name                                     = "description",
    nullable                                 = false
  )
  private String            description;
```

Finally, In the controller I have:

```
    public String updateProducts(
        @Valid @ModelAttribute("updateProductsForm") UpdateProductsForm updateProductsForm, 
        ModelMap modelMap, BindingResult result) {

        List<Product> products = (List<Product>) modelMap.get("products");

        if (result.hasErrors()) {

        modelMap.addAttribute("products", products);
        modelMap.addAttribute("errors", result.getAllErrors());

        return "updateProducts";
    }
```

I've tried everything I can think of but no matter what I do I end up with this exception at run time.

```
ype Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; 
nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
```

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request. If I remove the validation from the Product object, everything works fine (just no validation).

Exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't setup validation only jpa. You need hibernate-validator for validation.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Is the dependency for the validator.

Next to that the `BindingResult` must directly follow the `@ModelAttribute` annotated attribute, so switch the `ModelMap` and `BindingResult` attributes in your controller method also.

Comment: And? Is it working, isn't it? Post the full stacktrace if it isn't and show please the spring mvc configuration. (and tell us which Spring version you are using).